# Python Django: Why Google OAuth2 Token is valid after expiration time?

Tags: python, oauth, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

I am using Google OAuth2 flow as described here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server.

First I check if user credentials are already in a DB, if not the auth flow is initiated. After exchanging code to an access token, credentials are saved in a DB. There along with an access token and a refresh token a token expiration dateTime is saved, which is 1 hour (credentials.expiry).

Then I wanted to check how the access token would be refreshed. So I explicitly requested API after the token expiration time. The previously saved credentials are in the DB, so I get them from there. Its validity is checked, and the access token should be updated. However, by some reason, the token is valid and by making a test request to the Google API I am kinda can make requests, no error is raised.

I cannot get why token is valid, when it obviously is expired. I also checked the token validity here: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=AT and got { "error_description": "Invalid Value" }.

My code:

```
def google_oauth_init_flow(request):
    # get user id
    user_id = request.GET.get('user_id', None)
    print(user_id)
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    # set id to a state parameter
    request.session['state'] = str(user.id)
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), KEY_FILE_LOCATION)),
        scopes=SCOPES)
    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI

    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
        # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
        # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
        access_type='offline',
        # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
        include_granted_scopes='true',
        state=str(user.id)
    )
    return HttpResponseRedirect(authorization_url)


def google_oauth_exchange_token(request):
    state = request.session.get('state', 'No state')
    print(state)
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
        os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), KEY_FILE_LOCATION)),
        scopes=SCOPES,
        state=state)
    flow.redirect_uri = REDIRECT_URI
    authorization_response = request.build_absolute_uri()
    flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
    credentials = flow.credentials
    # save creds in DB
    try:
        save_credentials(credentials, state)
    except IntegrityError as e:
        if 'unique constraint' in e.message:
            # duplicate detected
            return HttpResponse('Violation of unique constraint')


def google_oauth_check_token(credentials, user_id):
    # convert dict into credentials instance
    if type(credentials) == dict:
        credentials = init_creds_instance(credentials)
    if credentials.expired:
        print('Token is expired getting new one...')
        # refresh credentials
        request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
        credentials.refresh(request)
        # alternative method
        # credentials.refresh(httplib2.Http())
        # update token in DB
        SystemServiceTokens.objects.filter(id=user_id).update(name='token', key=credentials.token)
        return credentials
    else: # always Token is valid
        print('TOKEN', credentials.token)
        print('EXPIRY', credentials.expiry)
        print('REFRESH TOKEN', credentials.refresh_token)
        print('Token is valid')
        return credentials

def get_user_info(credentials):
    user_info = build(serviceName='oauth2', version='v2', credentials=credentials)
    return user_info.userinfo().get().execute()


def save_credentials(credentials, state):
    user = User.objects.get(id=state)
    google_oauth_check_token(credentials, user.id)
    # get email
    user_info = get_user_info(credentials)
    model = SystemServiceTokens()

    # check duplicate values
    if not model.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, email=user_info['email'], service_id='ga').exists():
        print("Entry contained in queryset")
        model.token = credentials.token
        model.refresh_token = credentials.refresh_token
        model.expires_at = datetime.datetime.strftime(credentials.expiry, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        model.user = user
        model.email = user_info['email']
        model.service_id = 'ga'
        return model.save()
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Unique constraint violation')

# No errors

def test_request_google(request):
    credentials = SystemServiceTokens.objects.filter(user_id=9).first() # DEBUG ID
    print(model_to_dict(credentials))
    credentials = google_oauth_check_token(model_to_dict(credentials), 9)

    # test
    user_info = build(serviceName='oauth2', version='v2', credentials=credentials)
    print(user_info.userinfo().get().execute())
    drive = build('drive', 'v2', credentials=credentials)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the python client library can detect a refresh token its going to refresh it for you.   Assuming your code works correctly you should never have an access token expire the library will refresh it five minutes before it is due to expire.

My Python isn't the best but its probably this in the source code.
[http.py#L1559](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/cbb1f88b82b21f5cb9dcace33ffea3f95a189015/googleapiclient/http.py#L1559)